# Postgres Database Indexing

Tags: postgresql, unique

I want to create the constraint with some conditions. Since I can't do it Hibernate, I tried to set in the Postgres database.

Below is my indexing

If **instrument_project_id**  is **not null** then the combination of **name, instrument, instrument_project_id** should of **unique**.

```
create unique index on public.calibration (name, instrument, instrument_project_id) 
where instrument_project_id is not null;
```

If **instrument_project_id  is null** then the combination of **name, instrument** should of be ***unique***.

```
create unique index on public.calibration (name, instrument) 
 where instrument_project_id is null;
```

Not working as expected.

Comment: Apology. Actually not working as expected . If instrument_project_id is null then the combination of keys (name, instrument) should be unique. which is the first one .  If instrument_project_id is not null then the combination of keys (name, instrument, instrument_project_id) should be unique. which is the second one.

Comment: So what did you expect, and what do you get? Please [edit] your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below your question) and add some sample data, the result you expect and the result you got. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) [edit] your question do not post code or additional information as comments

Comment: Suspicion: is your problem connected to NULL values in `name` or `instrument`?